# Linking a DLL using xerces gives undefined symbols

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, xerces-c

I'm creating a shared library/DLL using cygwin which makes use of Xerces. When I call the xercesc functions from the main application everything is fine, but when I try to put some code into the library, then I get undefined symbols for all the static stuff that xerxesc defines.

For example:

```
std::string fromXMLString(XMLCh *oXMLString)
{
    std::string result;
    xercesc::DOMImplementation *impl =  xercesc::DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(X("Core"));

    char *temp = xercesc::XMLString::transcode(oXMLString);
    result = temp;

    xercesc::XMLString::release(&temp);
    return result;
}
```

Linking:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,cygsupport.so  -L /usr/local/lib -l xerces-c -o cygsupport.so obj/helper/xml_helper.o
```

When linking the library, I get:

```
/usr/local/include/xercesc/internal/XSerializable.hpp:37: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(wchar_t const*)'
/usr/local/include/xercesc/internal/XSerializable.hpp:37: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'
/usr/local/include/xercesc/internal/XSerializable.hpp:37: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::transcode(wchar_t const*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'
/usr/local/include/xercesc/internal/XSerializable.hpp:37: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'
/usr/local/include/xercesc/internal/XSerializable.hpp:37: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(char**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'
/usr/local/include/xercesc/internal/XSerializable.hpp:37: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'
/usr/local/include/xercesc/internal/XSerializable.hpp:37: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(wchar_t**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'
/usr/local/include/xercesc/internal/XSerializable.hpp:37: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'
```

...

Comment: Did you set up your path variables properly?  From the xerces site:  "You will need to add the xerces-c-3.1.1-{arch}-{os}-{compiler}/bin directory to your PATH environment variable:"

Comment: When I compile the main application, it works. It's only the shared library, that gives me troubles. My assumption is that the shared symbols should be forwarded somehow to the main app, and don't need to be resolved in the shared library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after several days on looking into this issue I found the solution. It is as simple as stupid.

My original linker commandline looked like this:

```
g++ -shared -o mylib.so -L/usr/local/lib -lxerces-c objects...
```

Googling on this problem didn't yield anything usefull, so finally I decided to create a fresh new sample project with eclipse and suddenly it worked. The only difference was in the commandline to the linker. When I applied the same order to my main project it suddenly compiled.

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -shared -o mylib.so objects... -lxerces-c
```

Note that in the above line, the objects come before the library, and apperently this makes the difference. I thought that the ordering of the libs only applies to the libraries, but apparently also the objects must be ordered appropriately.